# Cannot open document library in Explorer View

Tags: 2007, document-library, explorer-view

This is for a SharePoint 2007 site on which we have various document libraries. One of our users has always been able to use Explorer View on his department's document library but he was recently assigned a new workstation and, since then, has not been able to access it via Explorer View (though he can view it normally through IE. When he tries to view it with Explorer view, this error occurs:

> Your client does not support opening this list with Windows Explorer.

I've tried various solutions but nothing worked:

1. Make sure WebClient is Started and set to start-up automatically.
2. Go into Internet Options and add the website to the trusted zone (it was already in the list)
3. Try another web browser
4. Switch off protected mode
5. Install this hotfix https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2846960 (it was already installed)
6. Restart the machine
7. Give the user full access to the library
8. Replicate their AD access with a user who **can** access Explorer View (this did nothing at all, the user tried on other machines and still couldn't access Explorer drive while the user we replicated his access from still could)

I'm running out of ideas and solutions and have looked through various questions asking the same thing I'm asking, only the solutions offered in those questions don't work for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is os n browser version?

Comment: OS is Windows 10 and Browser is IE11 64 bit. I've tried installing 32 bit but it says it's incompatible with the current system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user needs to have Full Control of the site in which the document library is located before they can access Explorer View.

I had previously given the user full control at document library level and they still couldn't access Explorer View. So I granted them full control at site level and they were then able to access Explorer View.